# Program balance

Tags: program, storage

with solidity you can send  ethers from a wallet to a Contract. How should be the right way to send lamports from a wallet to a program? Should I create an Account to store the lamports and associate this account to the program? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Apologies, I think I understand the question better -- you're trying to basically collect fees from user interaction, and then store those fees in a program account, correct?

In order to designate a fee account for user interaction, you have a number of options, but I suggest the following:

Make an instruction (gated by a program admin address that you either hardcode or point to the program's upgrade authority) that allows you to update a field somewhere in a PDA data account on your program, call the field "fee wallet". This way, you can configure the fee wallet to something that you or the DAO have direct control over. Just make sure that whenever your program is supposed to collect fees, you always check for equality with that designated account against what the user provides in their transaction!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, actually my question was not related with the deployment process. I would like an instruction in my Program which be able to store solana fees. I mean, if someone is going use my contract i want that person should pay fees, so i need to transfer SOL from the program caller to a Program Account.

Comment: It is really helpful, i have to learn more about PDA, but i think this is the correct path. Again, thank you!